# When I click a Viewcontroller in storyboard mode, the layout changes

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Here's something very weird: ever since XCode 5 came out I've been getting this issue where if I click on a viewcontroller when in storyboard mode, it will reformat the layout. Is this a glitch? Or some effect derived from the new autoformatting rules? Below are the before and after images.

Note: this layout change can occur by clicking any part of the view controller but it isn't always consistent.

UPDATE:
Looks like this issue resulted from creating a loop between the view controllers (which xcode doesn't like). Breaking the loop solves the issue.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: If you run the app, which does the layout appear as?

Comment: The latter, unless I hit undo.

Comment: That's odd. What I was thinking was that Xcode 5, since it is designed for iOS 7 with translucent Navigation Bars, hides the bar when you edit the view so you can see the entire screen. Apparently, this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, and it only seems to affect a few view controllers. When I hit undo, it seems to put the formatting back except for the bottom toolbar which is slightly shifted. If I try hitting undo again it says "Undo Change is Misplaced".

Comment: Very unusual. In your code, have you tried setting the navigationBar.hidden = NO;?

Comment: No, but I think I've managed to figure out the root of the problem. I have a series of view controllers that connect to each other in an almost circular form (one pushes to the next etc and then the last pushes to the first). If I break the last part of the chain, the layout issue disappears. Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Basically, you were creating an endless loop of view controllers. Now this makes sense. Basically, if you have it like this, then you could end up pushing basically an endless number of view controllers onto the stack. Clearly not a good idea. This was probably IB's way of telling you "Don't do this!"

Comment: Ohhhh, ok that makes sense. I suppose I'll have to use pop back instead of pushing then.

Comment: Oh yes definitely. Just keep dismissing them back to the top. There is no need to go in a circle. THe Master view should only be presented by the navigation control. This view present others, not the other way around

Comment: if you solved the issue, feel free to answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resulted from creating a loop between the view controllers (which xcode doesn't like). Breaking the loop solves the issue.